# Calculate AWG from Cross section unit mm² and vice versa

Tags: c#, converters

I want to convert values in the [American unit AWG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_wire_gauge) convert to the European metric system in mm² and vice versa.

For instance I want to convert `11 AWG` into `4.17 mm²`.

I did not find implemented code so I added a solution here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While waiting for a better solution I use this code:

```
double Awg2CrossSection(int awg)
{
    var diameter = 0.127 * Math.Pow(92, (36.0 - awg) / 39.0);
    return Math.PI / 4 * Math.Pow(diameter, 2);
}

int CrossSection2Awg(double crossSection)
{
    var diameter = 2 * Math.Sqrt(crossSection / Math.PI);
    var result = -((Math.Log(diameter / 0.127)) / (Math.Log(92))) * 39 + 36;
    return (int) result;
}
```

The formulas are:

#### AWG to mm

[image: awg2mm]

#### mm to AWG

[image: mm2awg]